# Bijection Between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I was looking for a way to establish the equinumerosity of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}.$ This is what I came up with:

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ such that
$f(x)=x,$ if $x\in\{0\}\cup\{-\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}|n\in\mathbb{N}\},$ and $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x},$ otherwise. Here, $F_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number. Is this a valid bijection? If it is, then I'll be really happy with myself because this took me a while to come up with. Perhaps there's a more straightforward bijection I'm missing? Additionally, how would one go about constructing a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2,3,\ldots,k\},$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}?$

Note: Just so there is no ambiguity, $F_{0}=0,F_1={1},F_2={1},$ and $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: How about just mapping  $x \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ to $x + 1$ and keeping everything else in place?

Comment: @Magdiragdag, that's elegant. I'm embarrassed that I missed that.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, I'm not sure, but I think your approach also gives a way to construct a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2,3,\ldots,k\}.$ We just map each $x\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,k\}$ to $x+k$ and keep everything else in place. Is this valid?

Comment: However, I would still like to know if my function works.

Comment: It would be useful if you explained why you think your function is bijective. That makes the question easier to answer, and you can get constructive feedback if it turns out your solution is wrong

Comment: @FShrike, well, I started with the function $f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}$ since $\frac{1}{x}$ can never take the value $0.$ Then, I defined $f(0)=0,$ so that $0$ would be part of the domain. To preserve bijectivity, I had to go and redefine the function for the value of $x$ that gave $f(x)=0.$ This happened to be $-1.$ So, I defined $f(-1)=-1.$ Again, I had to redefine the function for that $x$ which gave $f(x)=-1.$ This happened to be $-\frac{2}{3}.$ Continuing in this way, I arrived at the definition of the function I have given in the question.

Comment: The [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem) should be mentioned in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are much straightforward bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ as the one pointed out by @Magdiragdad, your proposal is interesting nevertheless. I'll prove a general method for obtaining bijective functions from $X$ to $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ (when possible) and then I'll show that the function that you have proposed and the one proposed by @Magdiragdad are, in fact, both of this same kind.

$\color{#FF5200}{\bf{Proposition\ 1.}}$ Let $h:X\to X$ be a bijection such that the sequence of the nested preimages of $x_0\in X$, $\mathcal{H}_{x_0}:=\{h^{-n}(x_0):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (where $0\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow x_0\in\mathcal{H}_{x_0}$), doesn't contain $h(x_0)$. Then,
$$\Phi_h:X\to X\setminus\{h(x_0)\}\text{ defined as } \Phi_h(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{ if } x\in\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\\ h(x)& \text{ if } x\not\in\mathcal{H}_{x_0} \end{cases}$$
is a bijection between $X$ and $X\setminus\{h(x_0)\}.$

*Proof.* Clearly, $\phi_1:\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\to\mathcal{H}_{x_0}$ defined as $x\mapsto x$ is a bijection. Also notice that $\phi_2:X\setminus\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\to h[X\setminus\mathcal{H}_{x_0}]$ defined as $x\mapsto h(x)$ is also bijective because $h$ is bijective. Finally,
$$h[X\setminus\mathcal{H}_{x_0}]=X\setminus h[\mathcal{H}_{x_0}]=X\setminus(\{h(x_0)\}\cup\mathcal{H}_{x_0})\text{ since } h[\mathcal{H}_{x_0}]=\{h(x_0)\}\cup\mathcal{H}_{x_0}$$
So, since $\phi_1:\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\to \mathcal{H}_{x_0}$ and $\phi_2:X\setminus\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\to X\setminus(\{h(x_0)\}\cup\mathcal{H}_{x_0})$ are bijective and $\Phi_h\vert_{\mathcal{H}_{x_0}}=\phi_1$ and $\Phi_h\vert_{X\setminus\mathcal{H}_{x_0}}=\phi_2$, it follows that $\Phi_h$ is bijective as $X\setminus\{h(x_0)\}=\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\dot\cup(X\setminus(\mathcal{H}_{x_0}\cup\{h(x_0)\}))$. $\square$

$\color{#FF8082}{\bf{Example\ 1.}}$ Consider the bijection $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $x\mapsto\begin{cases}1+\frac{1}{x}& \text{if } x\neq0\\ 1&\text{if } x=0\end{cases}$. We'll prove via induction that $\mathcal{H}_{0}=\{-\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Clearly, $h^{-0}(0)=0=-\frac{F_0}{F_1}$. If $h^{1-n}(0)=-\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$, then
$$h^{-n}(0)=h^{-1}(h^{1-n}(0))=h^{-1}\left(-\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}\right)=\frac{1}{-F_{n-1}/F_n-1}=-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}+F_n}=-\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$$
Also, $h(0)=1\not\in\mathcal{H}_{x_0}$. Hence,
$\Phi_h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ defined as $\Phi_h(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{ if } x\in\mathcal{H}_{0}\\ 1+\frac{1}{x}& \text{ if } x\not\in\mathcal{H}_{0} \end{cases}$ is a bijection.

$\color{#FF8082}{\bf{Example\ 2.}}$ Consider the bijection $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $x\mapsto x-1$. Then, $\mathcal{H}_{1}=\mathbb{N}^*=\{1,2,3,...\}$ where, clearly, it is the case that $h(1)=0\not\in\mathbb{N}^*=\mathcal{H}_{1}$. Thus, $\Phi_h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ defined as $\Phi_h(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{N}^*\\ x-1& \text{ if } x\not\in\mathbb{N}^* \end{cases}$ is a bijection. Even better, since $x\mapsto x+1$ is also bijective, $1+\Phi_h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ defined as $1+\Phi_h(x)=\begin{cases}x+1 & \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{N}^*\\ x& \text{ if } x\not\in\mathbb{N}^* \end{cases}$ is the bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ proposed by @Magdiragdag.

---

In fact, the following Proposition is equivalent to the former and seems somewhat more natural and it's more convenient to contemplate the second bijection of Example 2.

$\color{#FF5200}{\bf{Proposition\ 2.}}$ Let $g:X\to X$ be a bijection such that the sequence of the nested images of $x_0\in X$, $\mathcal{G}_{x_0}:=\{g^{n}(x_0):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (where $0\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow x_0\in\mathcal{G}_{x_0}$), doesn't contain $g^{-1}(x_0)$. Then,
$$\Psi_g:X\to X\setminus\{x_0\}\text{ defined as } \Psi_g(x)=\begin{cases}g(x) & \text{ if } x\in\mathcal{G}_{x_0}\\ x& \text{ if } x\not\in\mathcal{G}_{x_0} \end{cases}$$
is a bijection between $X$ and $X\setminus\{x_0\}.$